# Correct syntax to remove concatenate characters from list column in data frame in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I know there are many posts and references for regex and `gsub` solutions, but nothing I am doing is working so I apologize if this is repetitive but I've been stuck for days.

I have a list of text  that looks like this in the data frame:

```
c("pop", "rap", "trap music")
```

While I would like it to look like this... remove the c, quotes, and parentheses.

```
pop, rap, trap music
```

I have tried so many combinations of str_replace and gsub. I have also tried to separate the the list into different columns using tidyr but would variables like "trap music" got split up into separate columns.  Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT:  This is the `str` for the column I need help with.

```
> str(Artist_Genre_final$artist_genres)   
List of 100    
 $ : chr [1:5] "canadian hip hop" "canadian pop" "hip hop" "pop rap" ...  
 $ : chr [1:4] "hip hop" "pop rap" "rap" "west coast rap"  
 $ : chr [1:3] "pop" "rap" "trap music"  
 $ : chr [1:2] "pop" "rap"  
 $ : chr [1:4] "edm" "electropop" "pop" "tropical house"
```

here is the str for the entire data frame.

```
> str(Artist_Genre_final)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Artist       : chr  "Drake" "Kendrick Lamar" "Lil Uzi Vert" "Post Malone" ...  
 $ Track        : chr  "One Dance" "HUMBLE." "XO TOUR Llif3" "rockstar" ...  
 $ artist_genres:List of 100  
  ..$ : chr  "canadian hip hop" "canadian pop" "hip hop" "pop rap" ...  
  ..$ : chr  "hip hop" "pop rap" "rap" "west coast rap"  
  ..$ : chr  "pop" "rap" "trap music"
```

Comment: Looks like it is a print issue.  Check with `cat` i.e. `cat(str1, '\n')`.  Do you have `list` column?  It is better to show the `str` of a small reproducible example.  Or is it a string like `'c("pop", "rap", "trap music")'`

Comment: Akrun's questions are pertinent. Still, for a single vector, you may find it useful to use `paste0` and set the `collapse` argument to `', '`. Like so: `c("pop", "rap", "trap music") %>% paste0(collapse = ', ')`.

Comment: Hi @akrun  I added the str to the question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @Vlad.c , I will try your suggestions, as I think it is a print issue.

Comment: You're welcome! If you'd like to transform the list column into a character one (separated by a comma and a space) you can do: `Artist_Genre_final %>% mutate(artist_genres=map_chr(artist_genres, paste0, collapse=', '))` (This requires `purrr` and `dplyr`).

Comment: Depending on what you're planning to do next, you probably *don't* want to collapse that column. Leaving it as a list will make it easier to manipulate later. If you'd like a different (less likely to explode your screen) print method, coerce to [tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced three rows of your data frame:

```
Artist <- c("Drake", "Kendrick Lamar", "Lil Uzi Vert")
Track <- c("One Dance", "HUMBLE.", "XO TOUR Llif3")
artist_genres <- list(c("canadian hip hop", "canadian pop", "hip hop", "pop rap"), 
                      c("hip hop", "pop rap", "rap", "west coast rap"),
                      c("pop", "rap", "trap music"))

Artist_Genre_final <- data.frame(Artist, Track, artist_genres=as.matrix(artist_genres), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then tested see if it gave the same as your str() output:

```
str(Artist_Genre_final)

# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Artist       : chr  "Drake" "Kendrick Lamar" "Lil Uzi Vert"
# $ Track        : chr  "One Dance" "HUMBLE." "XO TOUR Llif3"
# $ artist_genres:List of 3
#  ..$ : chr  "canadian hip hop" "canadian pop" "hip hop" "pop rap"
#  ..$ : chr  "hip hop" "pop rap" "rap" "west coast rap"
#  ..$ : chr  "pop" "rap" "trap music"
```

Seemed good, so printed with cat(paste())

```
cat(paste(Artist_Genre_final$artist_genres[[3]], collapse=", "))

# pop, rap, trap music
```

You need to access the atomic vector, hence [[3]], otherwise you get, c("pop", "rap", "trap music"), because you are printing a list of length 1, not the the character vector itself.

EDIT:

Here's a simple function to apply it to the whole list. Of course, there might be smarter ways to do this, but at least this will get you started.

```
paste_genres <- function(x) {
    result <- character()
    for (i in 1:length(x)) result <- append(result, paste(x[[i]], collapse = ", "))
    return(result)
    }

temp <- paste_genres(Artist_Genre_final$artist_genres)
cat(temp, sep = "\n")

# canadian hip hop, canadian pop, hip hop, pop rap
# hip hop, pop rap, rap, west coast rap
# pop, rap, trap music
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked, but I am wondering how I am going to do this for a list of 100 in one command. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Write a simple function to do the conversion from a list of character vectors to a single character vector in you desired format. I will knock one together and post it shortly.